# Magento2: Conflict functionality when i install third party module

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, third-party-module, out-of-stock

I have to use custom module for out of stock product shows at the end of product listing is working it but when I use third party module for layer navigation **magebees** than my previous **out of stock functionality stop** and out of stock product showing randomly in order. when I disable **layer navigation module** than previous functionality works it.

If anyone idea replies to me how to work on both functionality.